# How to add new locale for a language android?

Tags: android, locale

I want to use new locale for a language example:
French language for Japan locale or French language for China locale 
("fr-rJP" or "fr-rCN"), is it possible?

Comment: can you please post some code ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the formatted code block there.

Comment: Here is code: 
------------------------------------------------------------
public void setLocale() {
 myLocale = new Locale("my","rMM");
 Resources res = getResources();
 DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
 Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
 conf.locale = myLocale;
 res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
 Intent refresh = new Intent(this, AndroidLocalize.class);
 startActivity(refresh);
}
-----------------------------------------------------
This means I want to add new resource folder: values-fr-rJP in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create another values folder and name it according to your new language. values is the default, and keep your default strings there, and the new one name it values-jp or fr depending on what you need.
Copy in the new values folder the strings.xml from the default values folder, and simply translate the words accordingly, but dont change the variable name of each string.

And this is what i use to change the locale within my app:

```
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(THE LANGUAGE U WANT HERE); example ('jp' or 'fr')
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

Comment: Dear @Antonis Lambrianides, how about the case I need two resources folders for one language: one folder contain Unicode strings, one folder contain none-Unicode strings? Folder contain Unicode strings will be used Unicode font selected and folder contain none Unicode will be used when none-Unicode font selected.

Comment: can you give me an example? just to make things clearer